How can I have a colored Powershell prompt and still have conda env label?
When I add the code below to C:\Users\USERFOLDER\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:
function prompt  
{  
    $ESC = [char]27
    "$ESC[46mPS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) $ESC[0m"  
}

(as suggested in How to colorize the Powershell prompt?)
My prompt then omits conda's environment prefix (e.g. base), despite the environment being activated.
How can I have a colored prompt but still keep conda's prefix?
Other related questions that do not answer mine:

PowerShell prompt color issue
Invoke-Expression conda powershell prompt

Answers here that did not solve the problem either:
function prompt {
    $envName = (Get-Command conda | Select-String "activate" -Context 0,1).Context.PostContext -replace '>',''
    $promptColor = "Yellow"  # Change color as desired

    Write-Host "[$envName] " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $promptColor
    return "PS 
$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}

And the following seemed to be the other suggestion, but it wasn't clear to me from the code posted:
function prompt {
    write-host "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) " -foregroundcolor red -nonewline
}

I also tried
function prompt{
    write-host "PS " -ForegroundColor Magenta -NoNewline
    return "$((Get-Location).path)> "
}

But the conda environment prefix is still not displayed:


Add the code below to C:\Users\USERFOLDER\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
function prompt {
       $envMatch = conda env list | Select-String -Pattern '[a-z ]* \*'  # find activated environment, it has an asterisk after its name
       if($envMatch -ne $null){
           $envName = "(" + ($envMatch.Matches[0].Value | Select-String -Pattern '[a-z]*').Matches[0].Value + ") "
       }
       else{  # if no environment is activated
           $envName = ""
       }
       $promptColor = "Green"  # Put whatever color you prefer

       Write-Host ("$envName" + "PS ") -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $promptColor
       return "$($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}

This introduces a slight (probably less than 0.5s) to the prompt which I couldn't get rid of.
From my tests, it seems the delay is cause by the line with (...) conda env list | Select-String -Pattern '[a-z ]* \*'(...).
I find the delay a little annoying.

To use colors in powershell, you do not actually need any escape codes.
You can just do a write-host "text" -foregroundcolor red -nonewline to print a red color. The next write-host will be placed directly after due to the -nonewline switch.
Here's what my prompt looks like:
function Prompt
{

    write-host " PS " -BackgroundColor darkred -ForegroundColor red -NoNewline
    write-host "░▒▓█" -BackgroundColor darkred -ForegroundColor blue -NoNewline
    write-host (get-date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") -backgroundcolor blue -ForegroundColor white -NoNewline
    write-host " ░▒▓█" -BackgroundColor Blue -ForegroundColor darkYellow  -NoNewline
    write-host "░▒▓█" -BackgroundColor darkyellow -ForegroundColor Yellow  -NoNewline
    write-host "\\$env:COMPUTERNAME " -BackgroundColor yellow -foregroundcolor black -NoNewline
    write-host " ░▒▓█" -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor Cyan  -NoNewline
    if( (Get-Location).Drive -ne $null)
    {
        write-host (Get-Location) -BackgroundColor Cyan -ForegroundColor Black -NoNewline
        $networkdrive = $false
        write-host "█▓▒" -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline
        write-host "█▓▒" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan 
    }
    else
    {
        $networkdrive = $true
        $first, $second, $third, $folder = (Get-Location).path.Split("\")
        write-host "\" -NoNewline -BackgroundColor Cyan -ForegroundColor Black
        $folder | foreach-object {
            write-host "\$_" -NoNewline -BackgroundColor Cyan -ForegroundColor Black
        }
        write-host "█▓▒" -ForegroundColor Cyan -BackgroundColor DarkCyan -NoNewline
        write-host "█▓▒" -ForegroundColor DarkCyan 
    }
    write-host "PS " -ForegroundColor Magenta -NoNewline
    if( (Get-Location).Drive -ne $null)
    {
        write-host "$((Get-Location).Drive):\"  -NoNewline
    }
    else
    {
        write-host "\\$((Get-Location).path.Split("\")[3])\"  -NoNewline
    }

    if( (Get-Location).path.Split("\").Count -gt 2 -and $networkdrive -eq $false)
    {
        write-host "…\"  -NoNewline
    }
    if( (Get-Location).path.Split("\").Count -gt 5 -and $networkdrive -eq $true)
    {
        write-host "…\"  -NoNewline
    }    write-host "$((Get-Location).path.Split("\")[-1])"  -NoNewline
    write-host ">" -NoNewline
    return " "
}



This did not work. When I have function prompt {write-host "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) " -foregroundcolor red -nonewline} at C:\Users\USERFOLDER\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 it still has an extra white PS after the end of my prompt, and it doesn't show conda environment in front of it.

as I commented above, I tried removing the escape characters and using write-host, but it did not work. Could you provide a minimal version of your suggestion? I am not too familiar with Powershell code.  Thank you.

To have a colored PowerShell prompt and still display the Conda environment label, you can customize your PowerShell profile. You'll need to modify the prompt function to include both the color formatting and the Conda environment label. Here's a short guide:
Open your PowerShell profile script (Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 for PowerShell 7, or profile.ps1 for Windows PowerShell) in a text editor.
Add or modify the prompt function to include both color formatting and the Conda environment label. Here's an example:
function prompt {
    $envName = (Get-Command conda | Select-String "activate" -Context 0,1).Context.PostContext -replace '>',''
    $promptColor = "Yellow"  # Change color as desired

    Write-Host "[$envName] " -NoNewline -ForegroundColor $promptColor
    return "PS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}

Save the changes to your PowerShell profile script.
Restart your PowerShell session for the changes to take effect.
This modified prompt function will display the Conda environment label in square brackets with the specified color, followed by the standard PowerShell prompt. Adjust the color and formatting to suit your preferences.

This didn't work. The square brackets end up empty when I use this code.

I have adapted the logic behind this answer to create mine. Thank you.
